# How to create an event in observer which fired after adding customer in Magento 2.1.6?

Tags: magento2

I am new in Magento and want to create an observer (event) which should fire after adding a customer. I tried below tutorial but not working:
https://webkul.com/blog/observers-in-magento2/

I created folders and files as described in this but that is not working.
Any help will really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have created custom module to do this operation .

So in your Vendor_Module directory create one directory called **etc**.

In etc directory create one file called **events.xml**

Put below code in events.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_customer_save_after">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module_Customer_Save_After" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Customersaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create observer for the same . so create directory called **Observer** in your **Vendor/Module** Directory

In your observer directory create Customersaveafter.php file

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright � 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class Customersaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $_customerGroup;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        echo "Do your operaiton here";
    }
}
```

Note : **adminhtml_customer_save_after** event is called after adding the customer